# Add a button in editor to manually specify the syntax highlighting of the code

Tags: feature-request, editor

There are a lot of useful buttons in the editor to create a link, format as code, etc. but I miss a button to specify manually the syntax highlighting, particularly the `<!-- language: lang-none -->` I often use (and I do not think I am the only one).

Could we have this feature?

Comment: Can you not copy/paste out the text to an editor of your choice that does highlighting as you prefer it?

Comment: Sure that he can, but since it is allowed to insert language type for code parts (as specified in the question) it would be nice to have it selectable by a button (at least for beginners). I also add that post readability improves if code snippets are highlighted correctly.

Comment: is the language HTML comment trick documented somewhere?